# Слова написаны/написано

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно?

`Нет, там четыре слова написаны/написано неправильно.`

`Нет, там восемь слов написаны/написано неправильно.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, личное предложение или безличное, кто написал слова или что написало слова.

Если это безличное предложение - то написано - оно написало.

А если написаны были кем-то, то: четыре слова написаны мной или тобой.

Есть разница, например, *было украдено* - то есть у кого-то украли, и *были украдены* - были украдены кем-то, у кого-то. Множественная форма связана с субъектом действия, если речь идет не о том, кто совершал действие, а о том, по отношению к кому/чему было действие применено, то глагол согласуется в безличной форме. Украдено у кого-то / украдены им.

Если речь идет об одушевленных существительных, то предпочтительно:

Четверо котов бежали - коты бежали. Десят собак лаяли - собаки лаяли.

Как возникает безличность в предложении?

Если употреблять в единственном числе, то главным становится числительное, а не существительное, то есть количество объектов определенного вида, с утратой одушевленности:

Четыре кошачьего вида умерло - четыре вида умело - четыре умерло.

Еще наверное есть разница с дополнительными словами с которыми могут быть согласованы глаголы:

В комнату вошло двое мужчин - в комнату вошло сколько? - двое. - двое кого? - мужчин.

Но я бы написал: двое мужчин вошли в комнату. Основа - "вошли мужчины", их было двое, они вошли в комнату. Если же "двое мужчин вошло в комнату" - получается, что их кто-то туда запихивал и оценивал количество, сколько вошло, но кто - неизвестно. Безличное предложение получается, и странное, потому что мужчины как мешки с мясом напиханы в комнату. Хотя, если "два шкафа вошло в комнату" - уже не звучит каламбурно. А вот "два шкафа вошли в комнату" - это каламбур.

Однако можно сказать: в комнату у меня вошли два шкафа, - тут вошли будет согласовано с "у меня", поэтому предложение личное. Я ставил шкафы и они вошли, но у меня, а у не сами собой.

В комнату вошли два шкафа - получается вошло два накачанных бугая, а не предмета мебели. В комнату вошло два шкафа - речь скорее всего об обычной мебели, а не шкафах-качках.

То есть, если существительные неодушевленные(действующий субъект без личности - оно само произошло), то числительное тяготеет к единственному числу и безличной форме согласования глагола, в единственном числе среднего рода - обстоятельство > действия.

А если речь о нескольких одушевленных лицах или субъектах действия, то к множественному восприятию числительного и множественной форме глагола - действие > обстоятельства.

Comment: Это получше уже-с.

Comment: Я рад-с. И я дописал-с еще-с.